# Create an overlay over a table column

Tags: html, css

I have a table with 5 columns (`city, 1st quarter, 2nd quarter, 3rd quarter, 4th quarter`).

I want that if we already passed a quarter to display an overlay over that quarter's column. My problem is how to make an overlay that covers the whole column. I tried a solution but it would not cover the cell padding. Anybody has an idea how to approach that? Here is my code:

http://jsfiddle.net/7kp3atp7/1/

Comment: Try setting height to `104%`?

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because there are spaces between table `td`. You can either use `border-collapse: collapse` or modify your current implementation. For example i create an overlay using pseudo-element `:after` and apply it to all `td` that has class `disable`:

```css
/* line 452, ../sass/screen.scss */
 .year-calendar {
    width: 918px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    min-height: 260px;
    height: auto;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 8px solid transparent;
    padding: 0px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 30px 1px #adb2b7;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 8px 8px;
    -o-border-radius: 8px 8px;
    -ms-border-radius: 8px 8px;
    -moz-border-radius: 8px 8px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px 8px;
}
/* line 463, ../sass/screen.scss */
 .year-calendar th, .year-calendar tr {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
}
/* line 470, ../sass/screen.scss */
 .year-calendar th {
    font-family:"Gotham Medium";
    font-size: 15px;
    background-color: #0070b9;
    border: 0;
    border-right: 1px solid #adb2b7;
    border-left: 1px solid #adb2b7;
    border-top: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    display: table-cell;
    width: 182px;
}
/* line 481, ../sass/screen.scss */
 .year-calendar th:first-child {
    text-align: left;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
}
/* line 482, ../sass/screen.scss */
 .year-calendar th:last-child {
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}
/* line 484, ../sass/screen.scss */
 .year-calendar td {
    border: 0;
    width: 182px;
    border-right: 1px solid #adb2b7;
    border-left: 1px solid #adb2b7;
    font-family:"Gotham Medium";
    font-size: 13px;
}
/* line 496, ../sass/screen.scss */
 .year-calendar tr {
    border: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #adb2b7;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #adb2b7;
}
/* line 501, ../sass/screen.scss */
 .year-calendar tr td:first-child, .year-calendar tr th:first-child {
    border-left: none;
}
/* line 502, ../sass/screen.scss */
 .year-calendar tr td:last-child, .year-calendar tr th:last-child {
    border-right: none;
}
/* line 504, ../sass/screen.scss */
 .year-calendar tr:first-child {
    border-top: none;
    border-top-left-radius: 8px;
    border-top-right-radius: 8px;
}
/* line 509, ../sass/screen.scss */
 .year-calendar tr:last-child {
    border-bottom: none;
}
/* line 511, ../sass/screen.scss */
 .year-calendar tr:last-child td:first-child {
    border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;
}
/* line 514, ../sass/screen.scss */
 .year-calendar tr:last-child td:last-child {
    border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
}
td, th {
    position:relative;
}
td.disable:after {
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    background-color:black;
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    top:0px;
    left: -5px;
    padding-left: 4px;
    padding-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<table class="table year-calendar">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>City</th>
            <th><span class="q1"></span>Q1</th>
            <th>Q2</th>
            <th>Q3</th>
            <th>Q4</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td class="reserved disable"><span class="q1"></span>

                <input name="" type="checkbox" value="1" checked="checked" disabled="disabled" />
            </td>
            <td class="reserved disable">
                <input name="" type="checkbox" value="1" checked="checked" disabled="disabled" />
            </td>
            <td class="reserved disable">
                <input name="" type="checkbox" value="1" checked="checked" disabled="disabled" />
            </td>
            <td class="reserved disable">
                <input name="" type="checkbox" value="1" checked="checked" disabled="disabled" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td class="reserved disable"><span class="q1"></span>

                <input name="" type="checkbox" value="1" checked="checked" disabled="disabled" />
            </td>
            <td class="available active">
                <input name="" type="checkbox" value="1" checked="checked" />
            </td>
            <td class="available">
                <input name="" type="checkbox" value="1" />
            </td>
            <td class="available">
                <input name="" type="checkbox" value="1" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Boston</td>
            <td class="available"><span class="q1"></span>

                <input name="" type="checkbox" value="1" />
            </td>
            <td class="available">
                <input name="" type="checkbox" value="1" />
            </td>
            <td class="available">
                <input name="" type="checkbox" value="1" />
            </td>
            <td class="available">
                <input name="" type="checkbox" value="1" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Dallas</td>
            <td class="available"><span class="q1"></span>

                <input name="" type="checkbox" value="1" />
            </td>
            <td class="available">
                <input name="" type="checkbox" value="1" />
            </td>
            <td class="available">
                <input name="" type="checkbox" value="1" />
            </td>
            <td class="available">
                <input name="" type="checkbox" value="1" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Chicago</td>
            <td class="available"><span class="q1"></span>

                <input name="" type="checkbox" value="1" />
            </td>
            <td class="available">
                <input name="" type="checkbox" value="1" />
            </td>
            <td class="available">
                <input name="" type="checkbox" value="1" />
            </td>
            <td class="available">
                <input name="" type="checkbox" value="1" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Or in your example using `border-collapse: collapse`:

```css
/* line 452, ../sass/screen.scss */

.year-calendar {
  width: 918px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  min-height: 260px;
  height: auto;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 8px solid transparent;
  padding: 0px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 30px 1px #adb2b7;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 8px 8px;
  -o-border-radius: 8px 8px;
  -ms-border-radius: 8px 8px;
  -moz-border-radius: 8px 8px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 8px 8px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
/* line 463, ../sass/screen.scss */

.year-calendar th,
.year-calendar tr {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}
/* line 470, ../sass/screen.scss */

.year-calendar th {
  font-family: "Gotham Medium";
  font-size: 15px;
  background-color: #0070b9;
  border: 0;
  border-right: 1px solid #adb2b7;
  border-left: 1px solid #adb2b7;
  border-top: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  display: table-cell;
  width: 182px;
}
/* line 481, ../sass/screen.scss */

.year-calendar th:first-child {
  text-align: left;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
}
/* line 482, ../sass/screen.scss */

.year-calendar th:last-child {
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}
/* line 484, ../sass/screen.scss */

.year-calendar td {
  border: 0;
  width: 182px;
  border-right: 1px solid #adb2b7;
  border-left: 1px solid #adb2b7;
  font-family: "Gotham Medium";
  font-size: 13px;
}
/* line 496, ../sass/screen.scss */

.year-calendar tr {
  border: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #adb2b7;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #adb2b7;
}
/* line 501, ../sass/screen.scss */

.year-calendar tr td:first-child,
.year-calendar tr th:first-child {
  border-left: none;
}
/* line 502, ../sass/screen.scss */

.year-calendar tr td:last-child,
.year-calendar tr th:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}
/* line 504, ../sass/screen.scss */

.year-calendar tr:first-child {
  border-top: none;
  border-top-left-radius: 8px;
  border-top-right-radius: 8px;
}
/* line 509, ../sass/screen.scss */

.year-calendar tr:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}
/* line 511, ../sass/screen.scss */

.year-calendar tr:last-child td:first-child {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;
}
/* line 514, ../sass/screen.scss */

.year-calendar tr:last-child td:last-child {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
}
td,
th {
  position: relative;
}
.q1 {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: black;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<table class="table year-calendar">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>City</th>
      <th><span class="q1"></span>Q1</th>
      <th>Q2</th>
      <th>Q3</th>
      <th>Q4</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td class="reserved disable"><span class="q1"></span>

        <input name="" type="checkbox" value="1" checked="checked" disabled="disabled" />
      </td>
      <td class="reserved disable">
        <input name="" type="checkbox" value="1" checked="checked" disabled="disabled" />
      </td>
      <td class="reserved disable">
        <input name="" type="checkbox" value="1" checked="checked" disabled="disabled" />
      </td>
      <td class="reserved disable">
        <input name="" type="checkbox" value="1" checked="checked" disabled="disabled" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td class="reserved disable"><span class="q1"></span>

        <input name="" type="checkbox" value="1" checked="checked" disabled="disabled" />
      </td>
      <td class="available active">
        <input name="" type="checkbox" value="1" checked="checked" />
      </td>
      <td class="available">
        <input name="" type="checkbox" value="1" />
      </td>
      <td class="available">
        <input name="" type="checkbox" value="1" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Boston</td>
      <td class="available"><span class="q1"></span>

        <input name="" type="checkbox" value="1" />
      </td>
      <td class="available">
        <input name="" type="checkbox" value="1" />
      </td>
      <td class="available">
        <input name="" type="checkbox" value="1" />
      </td>
      <td class="available">
        <input name="" type="checkbox" value="1" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Dallas</td>
      <td class="available"><span class="q1"></span>

        <input name="" type="checkbox" value="1" />
      </td>
      <td class="available">
        <input name="" type="checkbox" value="1" />
      </td>
      <td class="available">
        <input name="" type="checkbox" value="1" />
      </td>
      <td class="available">
        <input name="" type="checkbox" value="1" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Chicago</td>
      <td class="available"><span class="q1"></span>

        <input name="" type="checkbox" value="1" />
      </td>
      <td class="available">
        <input name="" type="checkbox" value="1" />
      </td>
      <td class="available">
        <input name="" type="checkbox" value="1" />
      </td>
      <td class="available">
        <input name="" type="checkbox" value="1" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Your first example spans a row.  And I assume op wants the spacing between cells.